# Backup of Managed disks

Tags: backup, azure, microsoft

I need to delete some unattached managed disks in Azure. (they are not attached to any VM) In case of them being valuable I would like to know if it is possible to take backup of unattached managed disks. If this is possible please let me know of how I can do it and if this is not possible, what could be another solution for this?

Comment: Click the '+ Create snapshot' button for the disk.

Comment: How can I know which of my deleted VM's that had backup? Im thinking to not create a snapshot of the disks that had a backup with their deleted VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a snapshot of the managed disk, which will provide a point in time backup of that disk. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk).

Comment: How can I know which of my deleted VM's that had backup? Im thinking to not create a snapshot of the disks that had a backup with their deleted VM.

Comment: Look in your azure backup vault and check which VMs are registered and when they were backed up.